# Shopify Script Editor: bad decimal operation

Tags: ruby, shopify

I have a line in Shopify's Ruby script editor that is generating the error:

**bad decimal operation (0 x 4)**

```
BOX_PERCENT = BOX_DISCOUNT / BOX_PRODUCTS
```

BOX_DISCOUNT = 21000

BOX_PRODUCTS = 32100

both BOX_DISCOUNT and BOX_PRODUCTS are derived from Shopify script editor objects eg:

BOX_PRODUCTS = line_item.line_price.cents

Despite the error, it generates the correct calculation:

```
BOX_PERCENT = 0.690625
```

But I'm wondering how to fix the error.
If I change the calculation to the following it works fine:

```
BOX_PERCENT = BOX_DISCOUNT / 32100
```

So there must be something wrong with the formatting of BOX_PRODUCTS

EDIT:
After inspecting BOX_PRODUCTS with BOX_PRODUCTS.inspect I can see the number is a decimal:

**#Decimal:0x7fb946112140**

I've tried to convert it into a fixnum with .to_f, .to_i, .delete('.').to_i and %1 but that returns the error:

[Error] undefined method 'to_f' for #Decimal:0x7f260aa7c140

The original line_item.line_price object before I convert it to a decimal with .cents is:

**#<Money: "320$"> Class: Money**

Comment: I suggest calling `BOX_DISCOUNT.inspect`, `BOX_DISCOUNT.class`, `BOX_PRODUCTS.inspect`, and `BOX_PRODUCTS.class` to understand the exact types and values returned by those constants.

Comment: EDIT: Added this to original question with better formatting. 

Thanks @spickermann, inspect and class return:
Inspect: #<Decimal:0x7ff285550020>
Class: Decimal

I'm trying to convert it into a fix num with .to_f, .to_i, .delete('.').to_i and %1 but that returns the error:
[Error] undefined method 'to_f' for #<Decimal:0x7f260aa7c140>

The original line_item.line_price object before I convert it to a decimal with .cents is:
Inspect: #<Money: "320$">
Class: Money

Answer (score 0):

You would try to translate the instance of `Money` into a decimal first, like this:

```
BOX_PERCENT = BOX_DISCOUNT / BOX_PRODUCTS.to_d
```

Comment: .to_d generates an error: undefined method 'to_d' for <money>

Comment: That is very surprising, because [that method exists](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/money/Money:to_d). What version of the money gem are you using?

Comment: Looking at the page meta description on Shopify's Script Editor page it says: "The Shopify Scripts API is a simplified version of Ruby..." so I'm guessing that explains why the to_d, to_i etc methods dont exist:
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/shopify-scripts

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure this is not the correct way to handle numbers but I ended up converting the original money object to a string, gsub **#<Money: "** and **$** and then converting that to an integer:

```
price = line_item.line_price.to_s.gsub('#<Money: "', '').gsub('$','00').to_i
```

Comment: Please don't do this. If the error wasn't stopping you from saving the script in the first place, then just ignore it. This can blow up in so many ways.

Comment: The alternative is receiving 100s of error notifications each day so we cant really live with it.